# How to use withColumn with condition for the each row in Scala / Spark data frame

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have data frame with below format

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|DataPartition    |TimeStamp                |FFAction|!||IdentifierValue_effectiveFrom|IdentifierValue_effectiveTo|IdentifierValue_identifierEntityId|IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId|IdentifierValue_identifierTypeId|
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
|SelfSourcedPublic|2018-03-05T11:54:18+00:00|I|!|       |1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00    |9999-12-31T00:00:00+00:00  |4295903126                        |404010                                |320150                          |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+
```

I want to add extra columns with condition on below column

```
IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId
```

Add extra columns partition with below condition

> if IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId
>   =1001371402 then partition =Repno2FundamentalSeries else if IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId404010 then partition=
>   Repno2Organization

This is what I am trying to achieve that

```
 val temp = temp1.withColumn("Partition", when($"IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId" === "404010", 0).otherwise("Repno2FundamentalSeries"))
    temp.show(false)
```

And I am getting below output which but getting value as zero

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
|DataPartition    |TimeStamp                |FFAction|!||IdentifierValue_effectiveFrom|IdentifierValue_effectiveTo|IdentifierValue_identifierEntityId|IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId|IdentifierValue_identifierTypeId|Partition|
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
|SelfSourcedPublic|2018-03-05T11:54:18+00:00|I|!|       |1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00    |9999-12-31T00:00:00+00:00  |4295903126                        |404010                                |320150                          |0        |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+---------+
```

I am new to scala so asling basic question

For multiple condition on columns how to write when and Otherwise .
This is not working for me Getting error like

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   otherwise() can only be applied once on a Column previously generated
>   by when()

```
val dataMain = dataMain1.withColumn(
      "Partition",
      when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "EDInstrument" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Fundamental", "Instrument2Fundamental")
        .otherwise(when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "EDInstrument" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "FundamentalSeries", "Instrument2FundamentalSeries"))
        .otherwise(when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Organization" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Fundamental", "Organization2Fundamental"))
        .otherwise(when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Organization" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "FundamentalSeries", "Organization2FundamentalSeries"))
        )
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to the condition you provided, you should change the when condition as below.

> if IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId =1001371402 then partition
>   =Repno2FundamentalSeries else if IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId404010 then partition=
>   Repno2Organization

```
df1.withColumn("Partition",
  when($"IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId" === "1001371402", "Repno2FundamentalSeries")
    .otherwise("Repno2Organization")
)
```

Output:

```
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+
|DataPartition    |TimeStamp                |FFAction|!||IdentifierValue_effectiveFrom|IdentifierValue_effectiveTo|IdentifierValue_identifierEntityId|IdentifierValue_identifierEntityTypeId|IdentifierValue_identifierTypeId|Partition              |
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+
|SelfSourcedPublic|2018-03-05T11:54:18+00:00|I||!       |1900-01-01T00:00:00+00:00    |9999-12-31T00:00:00+00:00  |4295903126                        |404010                                |320150                          |Repno2FundamentalSeries|
+-----------------+-------------------------+-----------+-----------------------------+---------------------------+----------------------------------+--------------------------------------+--------------------------------+-----------------------+
```

**EDIT:**

Here is how you write nested `When`

```
val dataMain = df.withColumn(
"Partition",
when(($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "EDInstrument" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Fundamental"), "Instrument2Fundamental")
  .otherwise(
    when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "EDInstrument" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "FundamentalSeries", "Instrument2FundamentalSeries")
      .otherwise(
        when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Organization" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Fundamental", "Organization2Fundamental")
          .otherwise(when($"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "Organization" && $"RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType" === "FundamentalSeries", "Organization2FundamentalSeries")
          )
      )
  )
```

)

Hope this helps

Comment: The nuance in the nested when is (I think) where the closing parentheses are for the .otherwise() calls. This fixed my same error.

Answer (score 3):

One alternative way to implement this is that; you could use sql like CASE WHEN statement instead of using WithColumn

This might be easier to code for if you are familiar with sql

Eg.

```
       val dataMain = dataMain1.selectExpr("*", 
       """CASE WHEN RelationObjectId_relatedObjectType = 'EDInstrument' 
       THEN 'Instrument2Fundamental'
       WHEN cond2 
       THEN value2
       ELSE defaultValue end AS partition""")
```